# create matrix where all diagonals are the same value in anti-diagonal direction

Tags: r, matrix

I'm sure theres a name for this type of matrix but not sure of it. In `R` I want to quickly convert a variable `x`:

```
x = 1:10
x  #[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

into a matrix where all the diagonals (not the main diagonal) are the same in one direction, the anti-diagonal direction:

```
    x
1   1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
2   2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      NA
3   3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      NA      NA
4   4       5       6       7       8       9      10      NA      NA      NA
5   5       6       7       8       9      10      NA      NA      NA      NA
6   6       7       8       9      10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
7   7       8       9      10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
8   8       9      10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
9   9      10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
10 10      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
do.call(cbind, shift(x, 0:9, type = 'lead'))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    NA
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA    NA
# [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA    NA
# [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [6,]    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [7,]    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [8,]    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [9,]    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[10,]   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `embed`

```
out <- embed(c(x, x), 10)
replace(out, lower.tri(out), NA)[, 10:1]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    NA
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA    NA
# [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA    NA
# [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [6,]    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [7,]    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [8,]    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
# [9,]    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[10,]   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[11,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

Comment: @user63230 the class is simply `matrix` if you check `class(out)`

Comment: Sorry i meant name of matrix...identity etc?

Comment: @user63230 sorry, i am not sure  about  what name it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Here the alternative solution is using `base R`

```
f <- function(x) {
  y <- x:10
  length(y) <- 10
  return(y)
}

sapply(x, f)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    NA
 [3,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA    NA
 [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA    NA
 [5,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [6,]    6    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [7,]    7    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [8,]    8    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
 [9,]    9   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[10,]   10   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

This is much easier to understand, and does not require any package.

Comment: thanks but this isnt very flexible, it only works on `1:10`, lets say you have `x <- rnorm(10)`, it fails?

Comment: I assumed x is sequence of numbers as given by you. Will definitely update my code.